# Sending files via the new iOS 11 iMessage keyboard app integration

Tags: ios, file, imessage

I am trying to send a text file like a .txt file via the new iOS 11 iMessage keyboard app integration. Is that possible?

From what I could tell from the imessage (message) template in the API doc, everything about the in-keyboard apps have to be visual message when sent. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msmessagetemplatelayout

Can we send any time of file? If yes, what are its limits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send an file in an [MSConversation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msconversation)

> The MSConversation class represents a conversation in the Messages app. Use conversation objects to access information about the currently selected message or the conversation participants, or to send text, stickers, attachments, or message objects.

Using either

[insertAttachment :withAlternateFilename:completionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msconversation/1648184-insertattachment) which will insert the attachment into the message input field

or

[sendAttachment :withAlternateFilename:completionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msconversation/2909038-sendattachment) which sends the media file specified by the given URL.

Comment: Scriptable, so to clarify I can attach any file to a messsage on the app? Specifically a .csv file from the keyboard extension?

Comment: you should be able to yes